# How do I create something that loops?

Tags: python, loops

Im making a project for fun, and created a program that when I first made it a few months ago was ment to be infinite. How do I make it loop without making it copy and paste itself over and over?

## This part is to create a log in sequence.

```
if Type == "Admin":
      Username = input("Username: ")
      if Username == "Admin":
          time.sleep(1)
          Password = input("Password: ")
          if Password == "Pass":
              Help = input("Correct. Logged in. What would you like to do now? Type help for options. ")
              if Help == "help":
                  print("Here's a list of things you can run.")
                  print("Paycheck, Status")
                  Command = input("Which command would you like to run? ")
                  if Command == "Paycheck":
                      print("You are currently being payed $0.")
                      time.sleep(5)
                  if Command == "Status":
                      print(
                          "2 members online currently. Servers open: Admin and User. Users online: "
                          "Admin, "
                          "User.")
                      time.sleep(5)
              if Help == "Status":
                  print(
                      "2 members online currently. Servers open: Admin and User. Users online: "
                      "Admin, "
                      "User.")
                  time.sleep(5)
              if Help == "Paycheck":
                  print("You are currently being payed $0.")
                  time.sleep(5)
```

## Here I want it to once again ask what command they want to input, and never stop asking

Comment: Your indentation looks a bit off, but simply wrap everything in `while True:..` should achieve what you want.

Comment: Make function to perform your task and call this function recursively with some condition. By doing this you can avoid using ```while loop```

Answer (score 0):

This loops without end (or until ctrl-c):

```
while True:
  another_answer = input("What can you do with the pieces of a broken heart?")
```

If you want to loop until a condition is met you could do:

```
solved = False

while not solved:
    x = input("Try again")
    solved = x in ["some","acceptable","answers"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use while True to loop continuously, and use break in the while True to break out of the loop (if you want to).

Answer (score 0):

Put all your code inside while loop. like:

`while(1):
    #paste your code here`

Suggestion:

- First make a function of your part of code
- Then call that function inside the loop.

Comment: My code includes alot of its own loops, how can I integrate this into it? Just put EVERYTHING in it?

Comment: @Codarerxd, 4-space indents imposes a limit on the number of levels of nesting. Your code has a lot of nested indetations, that's why suggested you to first put your code inside function (let's name it 'loginCheck()') then call it inside the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it some thing like this, you can use your custom function in place of say_hello. It loops until you enter "break" in the input box

```py
def say_hello(inp):
    print(f"Hello, you typed {inp}")

while True:
    inp = input()
    if inp=="break":
        break
    say_hello(inp)
```